# Decode __VIEWSTATE sent in request

Tags: asp.net, encryption, browser, request

Maybe I am asking a very simple question, but I did not find any proper answer in google. Can we decode/decrypt __VIEWSTATE sent in ajax request? Is there any parsers of VIEWSTATE?